# openmp parallel for with non-PODs

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp

I'm trying to speed up a program, in the heart of which is a trivially-looking loop:

```
double sum=0.;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) // fails
for( size_t i=0; i<_S.size(); ++i ){
  sum += _S[i].first* R(atoms,_S[i].second) ;
}
```

While the looping itself is trivial, the objects inside it are not PODs: Here _S is in fact an 
`std::vector< std::pair<double, std::vector<size_t> > >`, and `R(...)` is an overloaded `operator(...) const` of some object.  Both of its arguments qualified as `const`, so that the call does not have any side effects.

Since some 90% of the runtime is spent in this call, it seemed a simple thing to throw in an OpenMP pragma as shown above, and enjoy a speedup by a factor of two or three; 
 but of course --- the code works OK with a single thread, but gives plain wrong results for more than one thread :-).

There is no data dependency, both `_S` and `R(...)` seem to be safe to share between threads, but still it produces nonsense.

I'd really appreciate any pointers into how to find what goes wrong.

**UPD2:**

Figured it. As all bugs, it's trivial. The `R(...)` was calling the `operator()` of something of this sort:

```
class objR{
 public:
   objR(const size_t N){
     _buffer.reserve(N);
   };
   double operator(...) const{
     // do something, using the _buffer to store intermediaries
   }

 private:
   std::vector<double> _buffer;
};
```

Clearly, different threads use the `_buffer` at the same time and mess it up. My solution so far is to allocate more space (memory is not a problem, the code is CPU-bound):

```
class objR{
 public:
   objR(const size_t N){
     int nth=1;
     #ifdef _OPENMP
       nth=omp_get_max_threads();
     #endif
     _buffer.resize(N);
   }

   double operator(...) const{
     int thread_id=0;
     #ifdef _OPENMP
       thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
     #endif
     // do something, using the _buffer[thread_id] to store intermediaries
   }

 private:
   std::vector< std::vector<double> > _buffer;
};
```

This seems to work correctly. Still, since it's my first foray into things mutithreaded, I'd appreciate if somebody knowledgeable could comment on if there is a better approach.

Comment: I think you may need to provide a minimal compilable example to demonstrate the issue...

Comment: What compiler? What version? OT: If you use `g++ -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL` you should get results that are known to work well, at least if [the fix for this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48750) has reached your distribution yet :)

Comment: @sehe: g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3 on lucid, compiled with g++ -O3 -fopenmp; your suggestion is definitely interesting, but does not fix the problem. And. you prompted me to run valgrind on it; it does not complain, but the results of valgrind ./a.out *are* correct (while just ./a.out gives rubbish). What on earth can that be then

Comment: Apparently swapping out the malloc/free routines _hides_ the problem in your particular program. I bet if you [preload tcmalloc (`LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so"`)](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) it will hide the problem too. I don't have the answer. I don't have the code, either, so I'm sure it will stay that way

Comment: We need more information about _S and R.  The overloaded operator may be what is causing problems, but without more information we would just be guessing.

Comment: What you are showing with your UPD2 code looks fairly reasonable.  The only comment I have, is that you have to be careful with omp_get_max_threads().  This gives you an upper bound on the number of threads that would be used if a parallel region - without a num_threads() clause - were encountered at this point.  This is not necessarily the same as the number of threads that you are currently using (i.e., the value returned from a call to omp_get_num_threads()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access to `_S[i].first` and `_S[i].second` is perfectly safe (can't guarantee anything about `atoms`). This means that your function call to `R` must be what's causing the problem. You need to find out what `R` is and post what it's doing.

In another point, names which begin with an underscore and begin with an uppercase character are reserved for the implementation and you invoke undefined behaviour by using them.